# Reasking a MathOverflow question

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, mathoverflow

I have basically the same question to ask as [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23654/pontrjagin-square-and-possible-typo-in-mosher-tangora) MathOverflow question.

I have seen what Tyler says there - I've been playing with it for a few days and unable to work it all out. I thought about registering on MO and just asking on that thread.  Unfortunately to leave a comment requires 50 reputation - reputation I can't see myself easily earning just yet.

So is it acceptable to re-ask an MO question here, asking for more details?

Possibly related thread [on Math.SE here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/310/vote-to-close-as-exact-duplicate-should-accept-mathoverflow-question-urls)

---

**Update**: The question has been posted:

[Pontrjagin square (Mosher and Tangora Question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54578/pontrjagin-square-mosher-and-tangora-question)

Comment: I wouldn't see why not. As long as you provide the link to Tyler's answer and say what aspects you'd like to have clarified there's certainly nothing wrong with that. As Aaron is a contributor here too, I'm pretty sure that you'll get some clarifications.

Comment: This is also related (to some extent): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your question is asking for elaboration on a particular answer, then it doesn't sound to me like it is really the same as the original MathOverflow question.  If you had the 50 points, then I think trying to ask as a comment first would be the way to go.  But because you don't, I think that asking it as a new question is completely reasonable.  The more specific you are about what you would like to have elaborated, the better.

Comment: thanks - better to be safe than sorry! I will ask the question

Comment: Thanks for the link from MO Jonas!